# Incorrect behaviour when inserting an item into the ListView with a custom controller

Tags: flutter, dart

I am implementing a `ListView`, where each widget in the `children` contains two buttons. These buttons are meant to add a new widget above or below the current one, as shown in the diagram below.
[image]
The issue I am facing is that when I click either button, the added widget is not positioned correctly, and the title is also incorrect, as shown in below.
[image]

I can't figure out how to fix it. Here's the full code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
        child: CustomListView(
          controller: ListController(
            items: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomListView extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomListView({
    super.key,
    required this.controller,
  });

  final ListController controller;

  @override
  State<CustomListView> createState() => _CustomListViewState();
}

class _CustomListViewState extends State<CustomListView> {
  late final ListController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = widget.controller..addListener(() => setState(() {}));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: controller.items.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => Entry(
        index: index,
        controller: controller,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Entry extends StatefulWidget {
  const Entry({
    super.key,
    required this.index,
    required this.controller,
  });

  final int index;
  final ListController controller;

  @override
  State<Entry> createState() => _EntryState();
}

class _EntryState extends State<Entry> {
  late final int index;
  late final String title;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    index = widget.index;
    title = widget.controller.items[index];
    print('build row $title');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => ListTile(
        title: Text(title),
        trailing: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            TextButton(
              child: const Text('Add above'),
              onPressed: () => widget.controller.insertAbove(index),
            ),
            TextButton(
              child: const Text('Add below'),
              onPressed: () => widget.controller.insertBelow(index),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
}

class ListController extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<String> items;

  ListController({required this.items});

  void insertAbove(int index) {
    items.insert(index, 'above-${items[index]}');
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void insertBelow(int index) {
    items.insert(index + 1, 'below-${items[index]}');
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you defined `index` and `title` in `_EntryState` and initialize them in `initState`. Those entries won't be reactive to the list changes and may also use wrong indices to get elements from the list. Move them to the `build` method so that they're updated on every rebuild:

```dart
class _EntryState extends State<Entry> {
  // Remove the late variables here

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final index = widget.index;
    final title = widget.controller.items[index];
```